# I notice that i have got error when will i run bin/cake servrer on my linux terminal I already install latest version of composer and php in my system

Tags: php, cakephp, composer-php, runtime-error

i have php latest version 8.2.10

composer version 2.6.3

when i want to launch my cake php to type this command bin/cake server i got this error please give the solution

```
PHP Warning:  require(/opt/lampp/htdocs/project/vendor/autoload.php): Failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /opt/lampp/htdocs/project/bin/cake.php on line 3
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Failed opening required '/opt/lampp/htdocs/project/vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /opt/lampp/htdocs/project/bin/cake.php:3
Stack trace:
#0 {main}
  thrown in /opt/lampp/htdocs/project/bin/cake.php on line 3
```

i give all chmod 777 permission of my cakephp project

i already update my composer

i also tried to run my apache2 server and put the project file inside the html and go to browser and give the path localhost/cake but it not work error is :- cant handle this request

Comment: Does the file exist that should be included?

Answer (score 0):

Check if you `vendor` folder exists.

1. If not then run `composer install` in you project folder.
2. If the `vendor` folder exists then something went wrong (maybe your `vendor` folder partly in your version control system like `git`). Try delete the `vendor` folder you run `composer install`.

Additional info:
I always run `composer dumpautoload -o` after `composer install` or `composer update` to have optimized performance and it solves some autoload issues if not every class is namespaced correctly. See: http://mouf-php.com/optimizing-composer-autoloader-performance